# Facebook graph API can't break down by asset

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get a breakdown at image and video asset level with Facebook graph API, but whenever I add image_asset or video_asset the response becomes empty, is there anything I am doing wrong or is there some API limitation I should know about? I can't find anything in the docs:

[image: Postman Request Screenshot]

With country breakdown it works fine but when I switch to image_asset or video_asset I get a response like this:

```
    {
        "data": []
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with FB we have solved a similar issue on our end. Perhaps it is the same for you: It can happen that a campaign in settings has 'dynamic creatives' turned off - in this case no data will be returned by the dynamic creative breakdown (as there is no data), but other breakdowns will provide data, which seems like it is the case for you. You can solve it by just retrieving ad data and then getting the creative data you need related to this ad. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have similar case but my ad is segment customization ad. which needs the adset.is_dynamic_creative to be set to false. 
I need to fetch insights for each body_asset, title_asset, ..etc but it returns empty array